# Convert numpy arry to csv file in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I want to save the numpy array as a csv file in python

For example given the following array

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

I would like to have a csv file like :

```
 1   4    7
 2   5    8
 3   6    9
```

My code bellow gives me the result like :

```
a.tofile('file1.csv',sep=',')

result:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I have tried the following code as well

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

df.to_csv("file2.csv", index=None)
```

which does not give me the desired result again

```
1    
2    
3    
4    
5
6
7
8
9
```

I would appreciate your comments and suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do `pd.DataFrame(a).T.to_csv('file2.csv', index=False, header=None)`

```
In [1210]: print pd.DataFrame(a).T.to_csv(index=False, header=None)
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply with `numpy.ndarray.transpose()` and `numpy.savetxt()` routines:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
np.savetxt('output.csv', a.transpose(), delimiter=',', fmt='%d')
```

---

`output.csv` contents:

```
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
```